# Boundary of the Difference

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove or give a counterexample for the following: given $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$. Let $A'=A-B$, then $\partial A' = \partial A - \partial B$. I'm not sure if that's true, but I'm trying to prove or give a counterexample. As I didn't find any point to start the proof, I don't have anything to show here, however I just want a hint on how to start. I don't want any detailed proof, I just want a little hint to get started with this proof.

Thanks in advance for your help. And sorry if this is too basic.

Comment: No question (that shows some effort) is "too basic" for m.SE, so never be afraid to ask!

Comment: My favorite way to approach these problems, is to use something I might call the pendulum method. You try to take as good a guess as you can, maybe with the aid of a few drawings or examples (someone mentions Venn diagrams of disks below). Then, you just go ahead and guess, either true or false, no harm done. Then as you go to prove it, you develop notions, context, facts, ideas. Then you might reassess whether you think it's true or false, and swing the "pendulum" the other way. You may go back and forth till you find the truth, and the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Think of two disks (in the same manner as a Venn diagram).

Comment: You stole my idea! just kidding...

Comment: @Clayton, very goood idea indeed. Now I've obtained $\partial (A - B) = (\partial A - \partial A \cap B)\cup (\partial B \cap A)$, I'll set out to prove this. Thanks very much for your help!